# Trigger IsVisible true- false of label on radio button checked- Uncheck in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show/hide a label using Trigger on `RadioButton` check/uncheck but I am getting the error. I can also do it in c# code by `inotifypropertychanged` but i want to use Triggers and this is my first time. I am not able to understand this error.

```
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10">

        <Frame HasShadow="False" Margin="10,20" CornerRadius="5" BorderColor="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BackgroundColor="#F7F7F7">

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <RadioButton Content="English" x:Name="rdbEnglish"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2"  Margin="2"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedEnglish,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Content="hindi" x:Name="rdbHindi" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedHindi,Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  />
            </Grid>


        </Frame>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10">

            <Label x:Name="lblrdbEnglish" Text="Note : Menu iteam changes will be updated next time" 
                       Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" >
                <Label.Triggers>
                  
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="RadioButton" 
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference rdbEnglish},Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"  >

                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Label.Triggers>

            </Label>            
        </StackLayout>


    </StackLayout>
```

Error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'bindable not an instance of AssociatedType'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TargetType` should be of type `Label` and not `RadioButton`.

From [triggers docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#property-triggers):

> TargetType - the control type that the trigger applies to.

```
...
<Label.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                    Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference rdbEnglish}, 
                                       Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
       </DataTrigger>
</Label.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir